# Why valid version of maven-sonar-plugin couldn't be found?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

We are using maven 2.2.1 and the compatible sonar-maven-plugin is 1.0, Sonarqube 4.0
Sometimes the builds are getting failed and when we checked the logs, we have come across with this strange error

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'sonar'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from snapshots
[INFO] org.codehaus.mojo: checking for updates from central
[INFO] org.codehaus.mojo: checking for updates from snapshots
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin: checking for updates from snapshots
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace

 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1569)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1851)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListByAggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionNotFoundException: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.DefaultPluginVersionManager.resolvePluginVersion(DefaultPluginVersionManager.java:229)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.DefaultPluginVersionManager.resolvePluginVersion(DefaultPluginVersionManager.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:179)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultPluginManager.java:1642)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
... 15 more
```

so we went to the location org/codehaus/mojo and then found that the maven-metadata-central.xml has the below content.

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
<metadata />
```

that is there is nothing mentioned about sonar-maven-plugin in the xml file , Prefix: sonar etc...

Tried doing the below: 
We added that(sonar-maven-plugin, prefix) in the xml files(central and snapshot), saved it and relaunched the build, then the build got success for 2days.

Now Again the same error appears!!! 
According to me some file/program is modifying this xml file.
could anyone tell me what is that file that is modifying that xml ?
And also why is the data in that xml erased? does it happen everytime the job is triggered? 
Does artifactory has anything to do with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show executed command? You have problem with: groupId (valid is org.codehaus.sonar, not org.apache.maven.plugins) and artifactId (valid is sonar-maven-plugin, not maven-sonar-plugin). http://repo.apache.maven.org//maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven-plugin/

Comment: Hi,
we have given this data in XML sheet.

<metadata>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</metadata>

Comment: In log you have: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin. Please write command which execute Sonar.

Comment: We have given "clean install" commands in maven Goals and options. And added sonar in the job in post build actions.

Comment: Can you prepare example project and add screen with jenkins configurations (job + sonarqube in admin panel)?

Comment: In org/apache/maven/plugins of .m2 repository , the file maven-sonar-plugin is getting downloaded and there is no version in this plugin file. because of this there is such error, no matter how many times i delete it, its getting downloaded sometimes(once in two days).

Comment: Adding the -U option in sonar post build actions in Jenkins resolved the issue for few days but the same error has started coming again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certainly facing an issue which relates to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4001 (see Sonar FAQ [1]).

delete the org/codehaus/mojo directory from .m2 repository as well as remote repository from which it is downloading.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/5010

hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to know how could we delete org/codehaus/mojo directory from remote repository. We are using Artifactory and remote repositories are added as virtual repositories.